# Trying to use AESCounterRNG in Android

Tags: java, android, exception, random

I'm trying out Dan Dyer's AESCounterRNG object from maths.uncommon.org and getting an exception. I'm using code that works fine in a Java project and am trying to understand why I'm getting different results in Android.

An exception is thrown every time I try to create a new AESCounterRNG using one of the supplied constructors. The exception error message is "java.security.InvalidKeyException: Only SecretKey is supported".

The code I'm using (in the onCreate method) is the following. There is no other code other than the single main activity and overridden onCreate and onMenuCreate methods.

```
byte[] seed = {-15, -67, -127, -15, -118, -45, -38, -5, 50, 49, 111, -29, 18, 81, -6, -104};
try {
    AESCounterRNG rng = new AESCounterRNG(seed);
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The API at maths.uncommon.org says:

```
AESCounterRNG
public AESCounterRNG(byte[] seed)
    throws GeneralSecurityException
    Creates an RNG and seeds it with the specified seed data.
    Parameters:
        seed - The seed data used to initialise the RNG.
    Throws:
        GeneralSecurityException - If there is a problem initialising the AES cipher.
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting different results in Android versus Java? I assume it's because of the underlying libraries. The stack trace shows that Android's OpenSSLCipher is called as well as javax.crypto.Cipher:

```
05-08 13:51:33.993: W/System.err(1335): java.security.InvalidKeyException: Only SecretKey is supported
05-08 13:51:33.993: W/System.err(1335):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineInitInternal(OpenSSLCipher.java:248)
05-08 13:51:33.993: W/System.err(1335):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineInit(OpenSSLCipher.java:300)
05-08 13:51:33.993: W/System.err(1335):     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:519)
05-08 13:51:33.993: W/System.err(1335):     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:479)
05-08 13:51:33.993: W/System.err(1335):     at org.uncommons.maths.random.AESCounterRNG.<init>(AESCounterRNG.java:114)
05-08 13:51:33.993: W/System.err(1335):     at com.example.securerandomtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pleased to say that Dan Dyer sent me an updated uncommons-maths library and it is now consistent under Windows Java, Linux Java, and Android Java. Problem solved. Thanks, Dan.

Comment: No problem. Just to clarify this, anyone can get the fix from GitHub.  The affected version is 1.2.3, so when I get round to publishing 1.2.4 that will include the fix.